# How do I write to a csv where the first row differs from the remaining rows?

Tags: r, csv, fread

I need a table formatted where the first line is a concatenated date and all remaining lines are two values separated by a comma. However when saving the file as a .csv, there is a comma after the concatenated date

Does anyone know how to remove the comma from just the first line in R?

R language

.....

```
sub = fread("C:/file.txt") # this is a file with two columns labeled as tmax and tmin

dt2<-"19810101"
setnames(sub,"tmax",dt2) # change name of column 1 from tmax to 19810101

setnames(sub,"tmin","") # change name of column 2 from tmin to a blank
```

I need a table formatted where the first line is a concatenated date and all remaining lines are two values separated by a comma such as shown here:

```
19810101

10.0,2.2

11,1,2.5
```

etc,

I created the table in R by joining two tables that each contained a column with the needed values (these are temperatures). I replaced the first column name with the concatenated date. I then replaced the second name with nothing (technically "").

```
19810101,

10.0,2.2

11,1,2.5
```

etc,

I am certain that the reason for the comma after the date is because both columns of temperature data had a column name (tmax, tmin) and the columns are separated by commas. However, how do I remove the comma from just the first line in R?

Comment: For future, add 4 spaces before code, and `` around code sections in normal text, when asking a question, makes it easier to understand

Comment: please add some sample data and your code you used to try and solve the problem.

Comment: As it stands it seems the first line without the comma would break the format of a csv. Maybe you want `writeLines`?

Comment: @Hector - thank you for the clarification. I read the directions for formatting but did not understand the 4 spaces.

Comment: @CT Hall - you are exactly correct. The first line without a comma is a big problem. I am looking at the writeLines option. This one is new to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"Here is a solution that isn't pretty but it worked. 
1. I wrote a table to a comma-delimited file with just the temperature values (no header)
2. read the table back into R as a single column
3. created a new file and wrote the concatenated date to the first line
4. appended the temperature values as a single column

....
dt2=19810101

fwrite(df, "file.txt"),sep=",", row.names=F, col.names=F) # write tmax and tmin values to a file as comma separated, no header

t=read.table( "file.txt", header=F,sep="") # read back in as a single column but with the comma between values, no header

fileConn<-file("file2.txt") # create a file connection to a new file; file will be created

writeLines(dt2,fileConn) # write just the concatenated date to the first line

close(fileConn) # close connection

write.table(t,file=file2.txt"),quote=F,sep=" ", row.names = F,col.names = F,append=T) # append single column of tmax and tmin to new table
....